# installing GoDaddy SSL in Amazon ec2 user

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

- I'm using amazon web service.
- I'm using linux instance
- I'm using GoDaddy SSL.
- I'm following this steps:
  http://jafty.com/blog/installing-godaddy-ssl-certificate-on-amazon-ec2/

I'm stuck at this point:

Generating a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) - Apache 2.x

2. Enter the following at the command prompt:openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr                                  Replace yourdomain with the domain name you're securing. For example, if your domain name is coolexample.com, you would type coolexample.key and coolexample.csr.

what I did was

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout 180.21.80.1.key -out 180.21.80.1.csr
```

I used the public IP address of my t1 instance.
I have generated a key and CSR files.

> 180.21.80.1.key
>
> 180.21.80.1.csr

like this. Now its ready to copy and paste in go daddy.

my question is:

- Is what I'm doing correct?
- Do I have to create a name for my IP address, like domains?
- Is it okay if I make mistakes? It's editable, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With reference to the link you mentioned try following steps

1. Ensure that you have installed mod_ssl and it is running.
2. Upload your certificates on Instance say /home/ec2-user/ssl
3. Edit /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
4. Find below lines and replace accordingly (Verify the filename and
   path are correct)

   - SSLCertificateFile /home/ec2-user/ssl/certs/site.com.crt
   - SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ec2-user/ssl/keys/site.key
   - SSLCACertificateFile /home/ec2-user/ssl/ssl_files/gd_bundle.crt
5. Restart Apache

Comment: hi, i think im on this part. how do i know if mod_ssl is running?
 where do i find site.com.crt? i only have `site.csr` `site.key` | Godaddy files: `4262b7fc267ecb1b.crt` `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`

Comment: To check if mod_ssl is running create phpinfo() file and search for mod_ssl module. site.com.crt is your 4262b7fc267ecb1b.crt file.

Comment: mod_ssl is now in Loaded Modules. When i open https://myweb.com  , it says `This webpage is not available`

Comment: Make sure you have https port added in your security group. For testing purpose you can allow all traffic.

Comment: its very difficult. am i forgetting something, maybe i have to convert crt files to pem files?

Comment: Dont worry its not that difficult. pem files have nothing to do with certificate files. Suppose you have uploaded certificates files in /var/www/html/ssl folder
with reference to your file name in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf file edit
 
`SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/ssl/4262b7fc267ecb1b.crt`
`SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/ssl/site.key`
`SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/html/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`

Comment: i already did that check this https://sslcheck.casecurity.org/en_US/sslcheck?host=1fxcash.com still no sign of ssl

Comment: the domain name is from godaddy, pointing to amazon route 53, is that ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78760/discussion-between-marlon-buendia-and-niteshd22).

Answer (score 0):

That looks right. Generally people don't use ip addresses as names of certs and csr's, they use hostnames, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. Also it's SUPER easy to add it to an ELB(aws load balancer) as opposed to configuring apache for it, so if you have your server(s) hidden behind an ELB, or you think you will add more servers at a later point it can be a little more convenient.

Comment: still haven't tested it yet, im afraid if i get a mistake, i would lose my ssl

Comment: if i paste the ssl, and get it all wrong, can i still take back my ssl?

Comment: I'm almost positive you can revoke it and submit a new CSR. I don't think you have anything to worry about. If somehow the format is wrong, which is unlikely, it will tell you when you submit it.

Comment: its says:
`Please choose a domain. You entered an invalid domain.`

Comment: ah.. ya I thought it was strange that you used an IP. But I think it is complaining about the way you answered the questions while generating the CSR. I think it's the Common Name question that defines the domain. If you are paying for an SSL cert you should attach it to a domain.

Comment: so that means, i should go back to amazon and setup a name for my ip address? like www.marlon.com

Comment: you will need to have a domain that resolves to your ip address and it should be configured as a virtual host in apache. OR you can point the name to a load balancer and upload the final ssl cert you receive from godaddy there and use it as a proxy to port 80 on your apache, nginx etc.. host.

Comment: hi i had this from amazon http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar.html#domain-register it wants me to register a domain which is $9. is there any other way to have a free domain in amazon? for the sake of testing

Comment: I don't know of anywhere that will give you a free domain. You could fake dns by locally editing your hosts file. I am beginning to wonder why you want SSL if you don't have a domain to attach it to. If you want to encrypt a connection to an ip address without paying for a cert etc you can make a self signed certificate but the users will have to click a couple of times to accept it. http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html - This is not going to achieve the usual goal of verifying and encrypting the connection to a domain but it sounds like that may not be your overall goal.

Comment: this seems to be fine for now. what are the negative effects?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with it. It's an uncommon approach to secure an IP without a domain name but it works.

Comment: what should i do? should i create a domain name in Route 53? is it possible to connect it to my instance?