# How do I turn my http website to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, web

My domain is registered on BigRock and the website is hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance. The system is live on HTTP.

Now we need to service the page as https and not http. Here the confusion starts.

1. Where does the SSL certificate go? BigRock or AWS EC2?
2. From where do i get a certificate? Bigrock provides [Cerfiticates](http://www.bigrock.in/digital-ssl-certificate/). What if i want a Verisign signed one?
3. How do I configure the DNS? point my domain to aws.ec2 ip and have the server inside ec2 host the https website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SSL certificate to be installed on EC2
2. You need to buy certificate from Bigrock but for that you need to generate csr and provide to Bigrock.

   openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt

   After this Bigrock will send you Certificate and Certificate Chain File which you will need to upload on instance and enable mod_ssl and modify httpd conf. Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294171/installing-godaddy-ssl-in-amazon-ec2-user/30295987#30295987)
3. In Bigrock. Select you domain and add A record with Instance EIP. This will point your Domain to Instance.

Answer (score 1):

heh, I just did this.  You'll see it fit to look through a few tutorials, but here is the baseline.

1) It goes on AWS.  More specifically, the SSL cert and https access goes on/through your EC2 Load Balancer (EC2 Console >> Load Balancers >> Listeners).  Then the connection between your load balancer and everything else is unencrypted, which is fine unless you need some crazy fips security setup.

2) You can purchase your cert from AWS, verisign directly, or BigRock and their affiliates.

3) You'll want AWS to be your DNS. Go to AWS console >> Route 53 >> Hosted Zones >> create a hosted zone with your domain name "myawesomesite.com"

a. Then you'll take the 4 name servers and give them to BigRock.

b. You'll also want to then create an "A" record to alias "myawesomesite.com" to your load balancer's url.

This is a high level.  You'll want to look up specific questions for each step. There are tons of already answered questions to this end.

**Documentation**

[look for "uploading the server certificate"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html)

[help with route 53 and aliasing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html)