# Transfer SSL certificates from GoDaddy to AWS (EC2-APACHE)

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

i want to transfer my GoDaddy website hosting to EC2 apache. But i do have a confusion that how do i transfer SSL certificates from GoDaddy to EC2 apache.

Do i need to export certificates from GoDaddy?
How to i install those certificates on apache, including priavte key?

Thanks,
Saqib

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294171/installing-godaddy-ssl-in-amazon-ec2-user

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as transfer SSL certificates when it comes to Apache.

You need to configure Apache server with SSL.

You can refer to the below blog post on how to do so:
https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-apache.htm